# Define alpha using ggplot to highlight single points

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, transparency, alpha

**Reproducible code:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

x = rnorm(10000, 0, 1)
y = rnorm(10000, 0, 1)

dat = data.table(x,y)
dat[,id := as.character(1:.N)]

ALPHA = 0.2 

dat[,alpha := ifelse(id == 42, 1, ALPHA)]
alpha2 = unique(dat[,list(id, alpha)])
alpha = alpha2[,alpha]
names(alpha) = dat[,id] 

u = ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, alpha = id)) + geom_point()
u = u + scale_alpha_manual(values = alpha, guide = FALSE) 
u
```

**Output:**

[image: output of code]

**Issue:**

The point with id = 42 is not highlighted, and continuous alpha-values are still applied to all observations. I would like to see only the point with id = 42 having an alpha of 1 and all the rest with a fixed value of alpha = 0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use annotate. Since the visibility is not very good when using alpha = 0.2, , I colored it red (but would work with an alpha argument too).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

x = rnorm(10000, 0, 1)
y = rnorm(10000, 0, 1)

dat = data.table(x,y)
dat[,id := as.character(1:.N)]

alphapoint <- 42

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2) +
  annotate("point",
           dat$x[alphapoint],
           dat$y[alphapoint],
           color = "red",
           size = 4)
```

[image]

Using alpha:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x, y)) + 
  geom_point(alpha = 0.05) +
  annotate("point",
           dat$x[alphapoint],
           dat$y[alphapoint],
           alpha = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve your desired result by mapping your `alpha` column on the `alpha` aesthetic and using `scale_alpha_identity`:

Note 1: I set the number of points to 100 because otherwise it's nearly impossible to see that this approach works.

Note 2: IMHO using opacity is not the best way to highlight one point, especially with a large number of points.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)

set.seed(1)

x = rnorm(100, 0, 1)
y = rnorm(100, 0, 1)

dat = data.table(x,y)
dat[,id := as.character(1:.N)]

ALPHA = 0.2 

dat[,alpha := ifelse(id == 42, 1, ALPHA)]
alpha2 = unique(dat[,list(id, alpha)])
alpha = alpha2[,alpha]
names(alpha) = dat[,id] 

ggplot(dat, aes(x, y, alpha = alpha)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_alpha_identity(guide = FALSE)
#> Warning: It is deprecated to specify `guide = FALSE` to remove a guide. Please
#> use `guide = "none"` instead.
```

[image]